# Using an array to store elements like a queue

Tags: java, arrays

I'm working on the hotel program and I have a problem with the my Queue class.
I need to create queue object in my program to add to queue and take from queue. Every time a name is added to a room it should use the queue object method to add the customer’s name to the queue. When the user selects to display the names of the first 3 customers my code should remove them from the queue one by one (first in first out) and display them as they are removed.

The queue should be based on an array. When the queue items reach the end of the array they should be added to the start or the array. If the queue becomes full the oldest queue item should be automatically removed and displayed.

The problem at the moment is when the end reaches 5 it should push the first input and take the last input and move it to the front of an array. Also please note the Queue must be based on string array. Please see the code i have so far, maybe some of you can help?

```
public class Queue {
static String qitems[] = new String[7];
static int front = 0, end = 0;

 void addqueue(String name) {

    System.out.println("Enter Queue Item :");
    qitems[end] = name;
    end++;
    if(end==5){
         takequeue(name);
    }
 }

 void takequeue(String name) {
     qitems[front]=name;
    if (end > front) {
        System.out.println("Item taken :" + qitems[front]);
        front++;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Empty queue");
    }
}

 void displayqueue() {
    System.out.println("Queue display: ");
    for (int look = front; look < end; look++) {
        System.out.println(" " + qitems[look]);





        System.out.println("end"+end);
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Comment: The question has a lot of mistakes. The title **Array String Queue** and the tag **queue** make it highly misleading. **Queue** is an entirely different thing in Java. Plus, you shouldn't be naming your class as **Queue** because it's an interface provided in the Java library. (_I've submitted a suggested edit. Please take note of that._)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **addqueue()** seems to have a logical flaw. Value of **end** gets increased by 1 before you check **if(end==5)**. When the value of end becomes 6, the if statement is ignored, the **takequeue()** method is not invoked and you face the problem. To solve this, either add the **if** statement before **end++** as

```
void addqueue(String name){ 
    System.out.println("Enter Queue Item :"); 
    qitems[end] = name; 
    if(end==5){ 
        takequeue(name); 
    } 
    end++;
}
```

Or check for **end>=5** rather than **end==5** as:

```
void addqueue(String name){ 
    System.out.println("Enter Queue Item :"); 
    qitems[end] = name; 
    end++;
    if(end>=5){ 
        takequeue(name); 
    } 
}
```

---

**P.S.** Please be more precise and clearer while asking a question from next time by using proper punctuation in your question description. Also see the *How to ask questions* section in the FAQ.